# HTML media query not being used

Tags: html, css

I've created a media query for a list of items to align differently for different screen widths. But I cant seem to get my media query to run. The following are my HTML and CSS code

**HTML**

```
<div class="a-checkpoint-list col-sm-12">
    <ul>
        <li>View</li>
        <li>Edit</li>
        <li>Delete</li>
        <li>Bye</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a-checkpoint-list > ul li{
    background-image: url(../images/checkbox.svg);
    list-style-type:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size:17px;
    margin-top:3%;
}

 .a-checkpoint-list > ul {
    margin-left:40%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.a-checkpoint-list > ul {
    margin-left: 15% !important;
}

.a-checkpoint-list > ul li {
    padding-left: 10% !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Try using `!important` keyword in your class properties :)

Comment: Don't use !important until you want to override the css. Your normal padding will be applied till resolution is 991px or less..in bigger resoultion 5% padding will be apply.

Comment: did you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` in your html code?

Comment: @Smart I have the following line <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized why my media queries weren't behaving the way they should've been. I put my media query at the top of my css file. As soon as I brought all my media queries to the bottom of the css file, they ALL worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

if all of your media query is correct but you can't get the output then check for this below code if you added on the html `<head>` or not. if you don't add this then your media query does not work.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media query is missing the opening bracket `{` :

Updated CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {

    .a-checkpoint-list > ul {
        margin-left: 15%;
    }

    .a-checkpoint-list > ul li {
        padding-left: 10%;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is there in my code. Forgot to add it here. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your forget to `{` to this . media query start than used to this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
  .yourClass{}
}
```

```css
.a-checkpoint-list > ul li{
    background-image: url(../images/checkbox.svg);
    list-style-type:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size:17px;
    margin-top:3%;
}

 .a-checkpoint-list > ul {
    margin-left:40%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.a-checkpoint-list > ul {
    margin-left: 15%;
}

.a-checkpoint-list > ul li {
    padding-left: 10%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="a-checkpoint-list col-sm-12">
    <ul>
        <li>View</li>
        <li>Edit</li>
        <li>Delete</li>
        <li>Bye</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that here. It is there in my code

Comment: @MichelleAshwini it's working code check to resize this window or used to google chrome mobile app

Comment: its still not working. When i resize the window, it still does not take the value inside the media query

Answer (score 0):

its a simple style error, opening brace is missing in your media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width:991px)
{
.a-checkpoint-list > ul {
    margin-left: 15%;

}

.a-checkpoint-list > ul li {
    padding-left: 10%;
}
}
```

https://www.your-plugin.com